# Move a file and all of its symlinks

Tags: command-line, scripts, symbolic-link

For the icon themes I'm developing, I have different files with a different number of symlinks placed in different folders.
Here is an example of one of them:

```
FlatWoken/FlatWoken/scalable/apps$ find -L ../ -samefile bluetooth-active.svg 
../stock/stock_bluetooth.svg
../status/bluetooth-active.svg
../status/blueman-active.svg
../apps/bluetooth-active.svg
../apps/blueradio-48.svg
../apps/bluetooth.svg
../apps/bluedun.svg
../apps/bluetoothradio.svg
../apps/preferences-system-bluetooth.svg
../apps/blueman.svg
```

What I would like to do is to find out a terminal command that is able to move all of them in a new folder (let's say, FlatWoken/FlatWoken/24x24 ), without loosing the symlinks (i.e. FlatWoken/FlatWoken/24x24/apps/bluedun.svg should symlink to FlatWoken/FlatWoken/24x24/apps/bluetooth-active.svg ). Is it possible to do so?

For more clarification, if I have this structure:

```
alecive@calliope:~/Scrivania/temp$ ls *
dest:
a

orig:
a  b  c
alecive@calliope:~/Scrivania/temp$ ls -l orig/*
orig/a:
totale 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 alecive alecive 8 apr  9 10:22 link_a -> truefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alecive alecive 0 apr  9 10:22 truefile

orig/b:
totale 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 alecive alecive 13 apr  9 10:23 link_b -> ../a/truefile

orig/c:
totale 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 alecive alecive 13 apr  9 10:23 link_c -> ../a/truefile

alecive@calliope:~/Scrivania/temp$ ls -l dest/*
dest/a:
totale 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alecive alecive 0 apr  9 10:24 truefile

dest/b:
totale 0

dest/c:
totale 0
```

I would like to fill the `dest` folder with the symlinks that point to `dest/a/truefile` (and not `orig/a/truefile`), without using the absolute path but only the relative path.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

**Advanced material**. Use at your risk! You will need to modify it for sure. Do not use if you do not understand it.

If you can live with absolute symlinks, you can do that. Suppose you start from this:

```
[:~/tmp] % ls -l a b c orig 

a:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rmano rmano 16 Apr  1 16:53 linka -> ../orig/truefile

b:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rmano rmano 16 Apr  1 16:53 linkb -> ../orig/truefile

c:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rmano rmano 16 Apr  1 16:53 linkc -> ../orig/truefile

orig:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rmano rmano 0 Apr  1 16:52 truefile
```

and you want to move the links under `./dest`...

Make the destination dir: `mkdir dest`

then you can use this script (save it as script.sh, remove the echo in the for loop after checking is doing the correct thing):

```
#! /bin/bash
#
# $1 is the "true" file name, $2 the dest directory
# note both must exist, no check done! Let as an exrecise!
#
# put absolute path in $absf
absf="$(readlink -f "$1")"
#
# loop over all of the links we found under ".". Avoid the true file. 
# Print instructions; remove the echo if you want to execute them 
# (after checking, rm is not reversible) 
#
for i in $(find -L . -samefile $1 | grep -v $1); do
        echo  ln -s $absf "$2"/"$(basename "$i")"
        echo  rm "$i"
done
```

...and run it as `./script.sh orig/truefile dest/`. It will execute

```
ln -s /home/rmano/tmp/orig/truefile dest/linkb
rm ./b/linkb
ln -s /home/rmano/tmp/orig/truefile dest/linka
rm ./a/linka
ln -s /home/rmano/tmp/orig/truefile dest/linkc
rm ./c/linkc
```

and you'll have:

```
[:~/tmp/dest] % cd dest; ls -l 
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rmano rmano 30 Apr  1 17:19 linka -> /home/rmano/tmp/orig/truefile
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rmano rmano 30 Apr  1 17:18 linkb -> /home/rmano/tmp/orig/truefile
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rmano rmano 30 Apr  1 17:19 linkc -> /home/rmano/tmp/orig/truefile
```

If you need relative symlink it will be more complex. You can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564634/bash-convert-absolute-path-into-relative-path-given-a-current-directory) to start coding...

Comment: I've edited the original post :)